# rolling window with 50% overlapping on window size in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I have a data frame like this which is imported from a CSV.
[Data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy67r.jpg)

I would like to create a sliding window of size 256 with overlapping of 50%. 
For example, window1 should contain data from index 0-255, window2 should contain data from index 128-383 and so on until all the data is split in their respective windows.
I am trying rolling.windows from pandas to create windows without any success.
I want to achieve something like this.
[Overlapping windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTCKs.jpg)
How can I do that using the optimized methods included in Pandas or Numpy?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**. This means no links or images.

Comment: should each window be a new dataframe? Or all windows should be combined in a single dataframe?

Comment: each window should be a new data frame

Answer (score 1):

```
def windows(d, w, t):  
    r = np.arange(len(d))   
    s = r[::t]   
    z = list(zip(s, s + w))   
    f = '{0[0]}:{0[1]}'.format
    g = lambda t: d.iloc[t[0]:t[1]]   
    return pd.concat(map(g, z), keys=map(f, z))
```

windows(d,256,128)
d: dataframe w: window size(256) t: overlapping factor (eg. 50% of window size i.e 128).
so after passing the above-mentioned parameters, the function returns a new dataframe with the window size of 256 with 50% overlapping.

Comment: how to do the same thing but with time, so the window size is duration based?
Pandas rolling has 1 frame overlap